# dropping rows in df according to max / min value per row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a big df for example workers and the number of hours each worker worked for a day

| worker | monday | thuesday | wedensday |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 3 | 10 | 10 |
| David | 2 | 8 | 1 |
| Chris | 1 | 4 | 2 | 2 |
| Goerge | 1 | 2 | 2 |

I want to drop all the lines of the workers who didnt work for at least 4 hours (it doesnt matter the day, if you worked for 4 hours even in one day the worker will stay, in this example only "George" will be dropped from the df)

I tried writing a function and tried using lambda but it didnt work and i believe there is a much easier way to do it

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

1. test whether worked hours are [greater than](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ge.html) 4
2. check if this is true for [any day of a worker](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html)
3. this gives you a boolean series, which you can use to [select the rows you want](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)

```
>>> df[['monday', 'thuesday', 'wedensday']].ge(4).any(axis='columns')
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool
>>> df[df[['monday', 'thuesday', 'wedensday']].ge(4).any(axis='columns')]
  worker  monday  thuesday  wedensday
0   John       3        10         10
1  David       2         8          1
2  Chris       1         4          2
```

Comment: thanks a lot! but what can i do if there is more than 5 days? i mean if i want to skeep writing the names of the days, is there some way more general?

Comment: @GilRodriguez you just need to adjust the `df[['monday', …]]` part, either add all columns that you want to consider, or drop all columns you don’t want with `df.drop(columns=['worker', …]).ge(…)`

Comment: yes i understand but i want to drop the rows no the columns,  for example if George didnt work for at least 4 hours at all (if he reached 4 hours even once he will stay but if not he will be dropped)  i will drop george... :-)

Comment: @GilRodriguez My comment is just answering the « more than 5 days » question. I mean that you can drop columns just for the computation of `.ge(4).any(axis=1)`, they will remain in the dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use boolean-indexing:

```py
m = (df.loc[:, "monday":] > 3).any(axis=1)
print(df[m])
```

Prints:

```
  worker  monday  thuesday  wedensday
0   John       3        10         10
1  David       2         8          1
2  Chris       1         4          2
```

Comment: thanks a lot! but what can i do if there is more than 5 days? i mean if i want to skeep writing the names of the days, is there some way more general?